# Why my Reactive form validation failed in Angular

Tags: angular, validation

my code as below:

html

```
<form [formGroup]="demo2Group">
        <input formControlName="demo2Value">
        <div *ngIf="demo2Value.invalid && (demo2Value.dirty || demo2Value.touched)">
            <div *ngIf="demo2Value.errors.required">
                the value can't be empty
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="demo2Value.errors.minlength">
                the value can't less than 4 length
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="demo2Value.errors.maxLength">
                the value can't more than 6 length
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

ts

```
demo2Group;
ngOnInit() {
    this.demo2Group = new FormGroup({
        'demo2Value': new FormControl(null, [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.minLength(4),
            Validators.maxLength(6),
        ])
    });
}
get demo2Value() { return this.demo2Group.get('demo2Value'); }
```

The `required` and `minlength` works,but the `maxLength` didn't work.If I use template validation.The input element can't input more than 6.

But now,I can input more than 6 and didn't show any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-val)

HTML:

> maxLength ----> 'maxlength'

```
<h1>
    Reactive Form Validation</h1>

<form [formGroup]="demo2Group">
    <input formControlName="demo2Value">

    <div *ngIf="demo2Group.get('demo2Value').hasError('required') && demo2Group.get('demo2Value').touched">
        the value can't be empty
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="demo2Group.get('demo2Value').hasError('minlength')">
        the value can't less than 4 length
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="demo2Group.get('demo2Value').hasError('maxlength')">
        the value can't more than 6 length
    </div>

</form>
```

TS:

```
demo2Group: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.demo2Group = this.fb.group({
      demo2Value: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4),
      Validators.maxLength(6),
      ]]
    });

  }
```

Comment: Thx,it works.Can you tell me why my code's error?If all the validators do not work,I can understand.But only `maxLength` didn't work.I am confused.

Comment: you should not put all validation together put them separate.or you can create common component for that.

Comment: Do not put all validation together? why not?

Comment: and you are using 'maxLength'' update it with 'maxlength'. hope you understood??

Comment: OMG! That's true! I thought two words are same.I understand it.